# Can't see own playermodel in thirdperson. Garry's Mod

Tags: mods, garrys-mod

Long story short, I subscribed to the playermodel "BlackRockShooter" on steam workshop, now I want to see how it looks when I enable third person by doing "sv_cheats 1" followed by "thirdperson".

When I manage to enable thirdperson I only see the man with the white gas mask and suit. I have clicked C and selected the BlackRockShooter player model, but it still won't show. How do I make it show? If it's possible at all.

(Other playermodels won't show either, stuck on the white man)

Comment: Did you kill yourself after changing your model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you change your player model into a different one, you have to usually suicide for the game to apply your changes.
(Easiest way would be to write "kill" into the console)